# How can I keep executing the same url n number of times in jmeter?

Tags: loops, url, jmeter, execution

We have a scenario where url is "xyz/abc/0". The count keeps on incrementing from 0 to n depending upon list of data we have in **table(id="tble")** where I have to take the count of total **id** within table and pass the value to next url

Comment: Please share your plan if possible or in textual form to understand it better and getting faster response.

Comment: Please check, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below plan:-

Below, using regEx fetching all the count or tr in the response:-

[image]
Using For each for iteration only. Not taking any output from it:-

[image]
Using counter to start from 1 and end value is fetched from regEx:-

[image]

Passing the counter variable to the URL request:-
[image]
This is just a sample, you can use anywhere as per your requirement.
Please check if this helps with your scenario.